Efficiently checking if an input can be parsed as a floating-point number in an expandable way in LaTex3?
I am trying to implement a function in LaTeX3 \check_if_fp:n that checks if an input can be parsed as a floating-point number (in an expandable way, so not using regexes). After a lot of thinking I ended up writing the code below that seems to work. I have 2 questions that are the following.
QUESTIONS:

QUESTION 1: Is there a more efficient way of doing it to optimize compile-time?
QUESTION 2: Is this code working reliably for all inputs or did I forget some edge cases? (and if so, how to make the code more reliable)

Note: The function I am trying to optimize is \check_if_fp:n: the debug version is just presented below to illustrate what is going on inside the current function.

%% -------------------------------- PREAMBLE -------------------------------- %%
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{xparse}
%% ---------------------------------- CODE ---------------------------------- %%
\ExplSyntaxOn
% User interface to check if an input is a floating-point number (* for debug)
\NewDocumentCommand\checkiffp{s m m m}{
    \IfBooleanTF{#1}{\check_if_fp_debug:e{#2}}{\check_if_fp:eTF{#2}{#3}{#4}}
}
% Main function to check if an input is a floating-point number
\prg_new_conditional:Nnn \check_if_fp:n{p,T,F,TF}{
    \tl_trim_spaces_apply:nN{#1}\__check_if_fp:n
}
% Check if empty and if not, analyze the input
\cs_new:Npn \__check_if_fp:n #1{
    \bool_lazy_or:nnTF{\tl_if_blank_p:n{#1}}{
        !\int_if_zero_p:n{\str_count_spaces:n{#1}}
    }{\prg_return_false:}{
        \exp_args:Ne \__check_if_fp_validate:n{
            \__check_if_fp_decompose:n{#1}
        }
    }
}
% Compute the length of a part of a floating-point number
\cs_new:Npn \__check_if_fp_length:nnn #1#2#3{
    \clist_item:nn{#1}{#3} - \clist_item:nn{#1}{#2}
}
% Validate the lengths of the different parts of a floating-point number
\cs_new:Npn \__check_if_fp_validate:n #1{
    \int_compare:nNnTF{
        \__check_if_fp_length:nnn{#1}{8}{9}
    }>{0}{\prg_return_false:}{
        \int_compare:nNnTF{\__check_if_fp_length:nnn{#1}{2}{5}}>{0}{
            \int_compare:nNnTF{\__check_if_fp_length:nnn{#1}{5}{8}}>{0}{
                \int_compare:nNnTF{
                    \__check_if_fp_length:nnn{#1}{7}{8}
                }>{0}{\prg_return_true:}{\prg_return_false:}
            }{\prg_return_true:}
        }{\prg_return_false:}
    }
}
% Return a list of the indices of the different floating-point components
\cs_new:Npn \__check_if_fp_decompose:n #1{
    \__check_if_fp_mantissa_signs:nnn{#1}{1}{1}
}
% Check if the head of a token list match some charcodes
\prg_new_conditional:Npnn \__check_if_fp_head_case:nn #1#2{p,T,F,TF}{
    \exp_args:Ne \__check_if_fp_token_case:nnTF{
        \tl_head:n{#1}
    }{#2}{\prg_return_true:}{\prg_return_false:}
}
% Check if a single token in a token list match some charchodes
\prg_new_conditional:Npnn \__check_if_fp_token_case:nn #1#2{p,T,F,TF}{
    \token_case_charcode:NnTF #1{#2}{\prg_return_true:}{\prg_return_false:}
}
% Step 1: recursively analyze the signs of the mantissa
\cs_new:Npn \__check_if_fp_mantissa_signs:nnn #1#2#3{
    \tl_if_empty:nTF{#1}{#3,#2,#2,#2,#2,#2,#2,#2,#2}{
        \__check_if_fp_head_case:nnTF{#1}{+{}-{}}{
            \exp_args:Nee \__check_if_fp_mantissa_signs:nnn{
                \tl_tail:n{#1}
            }{\int_eval:n{#2 + 1}}{#3}
        }{\__check_if_fp_mantissa_integer:nnn{#1}{#2}{#3,#2}}
    }
}
% Step 2: recursively analyze the integer digits of the mantissa
\cs_new:Npn \__check_if_fp_mantissa_integer:nnn #1#2#3{
    \tl_if_empty:nTF{#1}{#3,#2,#2,#2,#2,#2,#2,#2}{
        \__check_if_fp_head_case:nnTF{#1}{0{}1{}2{}3{}4{}5{}6{}7{}8{}9{}}{
            \exp_args:Nee \__check_if_fp_mantissa_integer:nnn{
                \tl_tail:n{#1}
            }{\int_eval:n{#2 + 1}}{#3}
        }{\__check_if_fp_mantissa_dot:nnn{#1}{#2}{#3,#2}}
    }
}
% Step 3: recursively analyze the dot of the mantissa
\cs_new:Npn \__check_if_fp_mantissa_dot:nnn #1#2#3{
    \tl_if_empty:nTF{#1}{#3,#2,#2,#2,#2,#2,#2}{
        \__check_if_fp_head_case:nnTF{#1}{.{}}{
            \exp_args:Neee \__check_if_fp_mantissa_fractional:nnn{
                \tl_tail:n{#1}
            }{\int_eval:n{#2 + 1}}{#3,\int_eval:n{#2 + 1}}
        }{\__check_if_fp_exponent_symbol:nnn{#1}{#2}{#3,#2,#2}}
    }
}
% Step 4: recursively analyze the fractional digits of the mantissa
\cs_new:Npn \__check_if_fp_mantissa_fractional:nnn #1#2#3{
    \tl_if_empty:nTF{#1}{#3,#2,#2,#2,#2,#2}{
        \__check_if_fp_head_case:nnTF{#1}{0{}1{}2{}3{}4{}5{}6{}7{}8{}9{}}{
            \exp_args:Nee \__check_if_fp_mantissa_fractional:nnn{
                \tl_tail:n{#1}
            }{\int_eval:n{#2 + 1}}{#3}
        }{\__check_if_fp_exponent_symbol:nnn{#1}{#2}{#3,#2}}
    }
}
% Step 5: recursively analyze the symbol of the exponent
\cs_new:Npn \__check_if_fp_exponent_symbol:nnn #1#2#3{
    \tl_if_empty:nTF{#1}{#3,#2,#2,#2,#2}{
        \__check_if_fp_head_case:nnTF{#1}{E{}e{}}{
            \exp_args:Neee \__check_if_fp_exponent_signs:nnn{
                \tl_tail:n{#1}
            }{\int_eval:n{#2 + 1}}{#3,\int_eval:n{#2 + 1}}
        }{
            \exp_args:Nne \__check_if_fp_remainder:nnn{}{
                \int_eval:n{#2 + \tl_count:n{#1}}
            }{#3,#2,#2,#2}
        }
    }
}
% Step 6: recursively analyze the signs of the exponent
\cs_new:Npn \__check_if_fp_exponent_signs:nnn #1#2#3{
    \tl_if_empty:nTF{#1}{#3,#2,#2,#2}{
        \__check_if_fp_head_case:nnTF{#1}{+{}-{}}{
            \exp_args:Nee \__check_if_fp_exponent_signs:nnn{
                \tl_tail:n{#1}
            }{\int_eval:n{#2 + 1}}{#3}
        }{\__check_if_fp_exponent_digits:nnn{#1}{#2}{#3,#2}}
    }
}
% Step 7: recursively analyze the digits of the exponent
\cs_new:Npn \__check_if_fp_exponent_digits:nnn #1#2#3{
    \tl_if_empty:nTF{#1}{#3,#2,#2}{
        \__check_if_fp_head_case:nnTF{#1}{0{}1{}2{}3{}4{}5{}6{}7{}8{}9{}}{
            \exp_args:Nee \__check_if_fp_exponent_digits:nnn{
                \tl_tail:n{#1}
            }{\int_eval:n{#2 + 1}}{#3}
        }{
            \exp_args:Nne \__check_if_fp_remainder:nnn{}{
                \int_eval:n{#2 + \tl_count:n{#1}}
            }{#3,#2}
        }
    }
}
% Step 8: ends the recursion with what remains in the input
\cs_new:Npn \__check_if_fp_remainder:nnn #1#2#3{#3,#2}
% Helper function to display the several floating-point components
\cs_new:Nn \check_if_fp_debug:n{
    \clist_set:Ne \l_tmpa_clist{\__check_if_fp_decompose:n{#1}}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}\hline
    DESCRIPTION&INDEX&CONTENT&LENGTH\\\hline
    INPUT&&#1&\\\hline
    LIST&&\clist_use:Nn \l_tmpa_clist{,}&\clist_count:N \l_tmpa_clist\\\hline
    \__check_if_fp_debug_row:nnNn{mantissa-signs}{#1}\l_tmpa_clist{1}
    \__check_if_fp_debug_row:nnNn{mantissa-integer}{#1}\l_tmpa_clist{2}
    \__check_if_fp_debug_row:nnNn{mantissa-dot}{#1}\l_tmpa_clist{3}
    \__check_if_fp_debug_row:nnNn{mantissa-fractional}{#1}\l_tmpa_clist{4}
    \__check_if_fp_debug_row:nnNn{exponent-symbol}{#1}\l_tmpa_clist{5}
    \__check_if_fp_debug_row:nnNn{exponent-signs}{#1}\l_tmpa_clist{6}
    \__check_if_fp_debug_row:nnNn{exponent-digits}{#1}\l_tmpa_clist{7}
    \__check_if_fp_debug_row:nnNn{remainder}{#1}\l_tmpa_clist{8}
    \hline
    OUTPUT&&\check_if_fp:nTF{#1}{TRUE}{FALSE}&\\\hline
    \end{tabular}
}
% Helper function to display a floating-point row
\cs_new:Npn \__check_if_fp_debug_row:nnNn #1#2#3#4{
    #1&#4&
    \tl_range:nnn{#2}{\clist_item:Nn #3{#4}}{\clist_item:Nn #3{#4 + 1} - 1}&
    \int_eval:n{\clist_item:Nn #3{#4 + 1} - \clist_item:Nn #3{#4}}\\
}
% Variants
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \check_if_fp_debug:n{e}
\prg_generate_conditional_variant:Nnn \check_if_fp:n{e}{p,T,F,TF}
\ExplSyntaxOff
%% ---------------------------------- TEST ---------------------------------- %%
\begin{document}
\checkiffp*{}{T}{F}
\checkiffp*{42}{T}{F}
\checkiffp*{.1e+2}{T}{F}
\checkiffp*{-12.5e+2}{T}{F}
\checkiffp*{12.5e+}{T}{F}
\checkiffp*{12.5e+X}{T}{F}
\end{document}
%% -------------------------------------------------------------------------- %%


The output for -12.5e+2 looks like (the list on the second line is a list of indices corresponding to the different subparts of the floating-point number):


What's the aim here? One can only really test an fp expression by fully evaluating it, e.g. sin(2pi)^4 would be valid but not in your tests ...

\fpeval is expandable and raises the expandable error ! Use of \??? doesn't match its definition on \fpeval{abc} so it isn't clear what your pre-check could do that this isn't already doing?

@DavidCarlisle I guess one reason might be if you don't want to raise an error if it isn't an fp. something like the .try handlers in pgf.

@cfr yes but probably you can locally divert the expl3 expandable error handler so just let fpeval do the work and catch its errors rather than having to duplicate the entire parse

@DavidCarlisle ok, but it is (to say the least) not obvious that it is possible to 'locally divert the expl3 expandable error handler'. if I read a basic introduction to a scripting language, I almost certainly learn how to do the equivalent, but it isn't at all obvious how to do that in tex. so for (la)tex, I instead try to figure out whether the input is valid first. I have no idea what the equivalent of 2>&1 or /dev/null or whatever is.

Well, I just implemented something similar to test for valid JSON numbers in the recent update of the jsonparse package. The JSON spec has quite strict rules here, so something like .5 would be invalid due to the missing leading zero. Maybe you can get some insights there and of course I am also always happy to receive hints for optimisation!

@DavidCarlisle How would you catch an error before it is raised? How would you hook into the error handlers of the relevant code? Is there some explanation in some expl3 manual about how to do that? Or would it boil down to redefining the relevant \msg_ command?

@JasperHabicht well... the documentation says Another particularity of expandable messages is that they cannot be redirected or turned off by the user. but the code is available.... how hard can it be:-)

@DavidCarlisle Right, let me think a while about this …

@JasperHabicht I'd overload the relevant \msg_ commands, adding a flag to it to branch whether to throw the error or leave something predefined in the input stream instead.

@Vincent do you want to accept anything supported by l3fp as true for your test or only a predefined valid number format like for instance scientific notation?

Conceptually, expl3 follows TeX - the 'try' approach isn't really supported as users are expected to fix their input if there is an issue - in the end, no output is better than erroneous output for a typesetting system.

I think you could catch some kinds of erroneous input using @DavidCarlisle's suggestion, but I have no idea how you'd catch the kind of erroneous input which generates tex errors and doesn't involve the msg system at all.

If your objective is to only parse for a valid float in scientific format (so something matching the regex ^[+-]*(\d+.?\d*|.\d+)(e[+-]*\d+)?$), the following defines an etl based parser for this. The result is roughly 12 times faster than your code (on the expl3 layer, I did benchmark your \check_if_fp:nTF macro with the testcases given in your question against my implementation).
\ExplSyntaxOn
\RequirePackage{etl}
% possible states of the parser
\NewDocumentCommand\myeckiffp{m m m}{
  \my_if_fp:eTF{#1}{#2}{#3}
}
\prg_generate_conditional_variant:Nnn \my_if_fp:n { e } { TF }
\prg_new_conditional:Npnn \my_if_fp:n #1 { TF, T, F, p }
  {
    \if:w
        t
        \tl_trim_spaces_apply:nN {#1} \__my_if_fp:n
        t
      \prg_return_true:
    \else:
      \prg_return_false:
    \fi:
  }
\cs_new:Npn \__my_if_fp:n #1
  { \exp_args:No \__my_if_fp_aux:n { \tl_to_str:n {#1} } }
\cs_new:Npn \__my_if_fp_aux:n #1
  {
    \etl_act:nnnnnn
      \__my_if_fp_state_sign:nN
      { \etl_act_break:n f }
      { \etl_act_break:n f }
      \use_i:nn
      {f}
      {#1}
  }
\cs_new:Npn \__my_if_fp_state_sign:nN #1#2
  {
    \my_if_digit:NTF #2
      {
        \etl_act_status:n {}
        \etl_act_switch_normal:n \__my_if_fp_state_int:nN
      }
      {
        \token_case_meaning:NnF #2
          {
            + {}
            - {}
            . { \etl_act_switch_normal:n \__my_if_fp_state_frac_req:nN }
          }
          { \etl_act_break:n f }
      }
  }
\cs_new:Npn \__my_if_fp_state_frac_req:nN #1#2
  {
    \my_if_digit:NTF #2
      {
        \etl_act_status:n {}
        \etl_act_switch_normal:n \__my_if_fp_state_frac:nN
      }
      { \etl_act_break:n f }
  }
\cs_new:Npn \__my_if_fp_state_int:nN #1#2
  {
    \my_if_digit:NF #2
      {
        \token_case_charcode:NnF #2
          {
            . { \etl_act_switch_normal:n \__my_if_fp_state_frac:nN }
            e {
                \etl_act_status:n f
                \etl_act_switch_normal:n \__my_if_fp_state_exp:nN
              }
          }
          { \etl_act_break:n f }
      }
  }
\cs_new:Npn \__my_if_fp_state_frac:nN #1#2
  {
    \my_if_digit:NF #2
      {
        \token_if_eq_charcode:NNTF #2 e
          {
            \etl_act_status:n f
            \etl_act_switch_normal:n \__my_if_fp_state_exp:nN
          }
          { \etl_act_break:n f }
      }
  }
\cs_new:Npn \__my_if_fp_state_exp:nN #1#2
  {
    \my_if_digit:NTF #2
      {
        \etl_act_status:n {}
        \etl_act_switch_normal:n \__my_if_fp_state_expnum:nN
      }
      {
        \token_case_meaning:NnF #2
          {
            + {}
            - {}
          }
          { \etl_act_break:n f }
      }
  }
\cs_new:Npn \__my_if_fp_state_expnum:nN #1#2
  { \my_if_digit:NF #2 { \etl_act_break:n f } }
\prg_new_conditional:Npnn \my_if_digit:N #1 { TF, F }
  {
    \if_int_compare:w 1 < 1#1\exp_stop_f:
      \prg_return_true:
    \else:
      \prg_return_false:
    \fi:
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff


But we can still be faster by defining our own loop that utilises that the input gets stringified, instead of using etl. The following defines basically the exact same logic as the code above, but without using etl, instead we use a simple loop which uses \s_stop as its termination token and \q_nil as a marker to gobble the remainder if we're done.
The result is roughly 2.4 times faster than the etl loop.
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand\MYeckiffp{m m m}{
  \MY_if_fp:eTF{#1}{#2}{#3}
}
\prg_generate_conditional_variant:Nnn \MY_if_fp:n { e } { TF }
\prg_new_conditional:Npnn \MY_if_fp:n #1 { TF, T, F, p }
  {
    \if:w
        t
        \tl_trim_spaces_apply:nN {#1} \__MY_if_fp:n
        t
      \prg_return_true:
    \else:
      \prg_return_false:
    \fi:
  }
\cs_new:Npn \__MY_if_fp:n #1
  { \exp_args:No \__MY_if_fp_aux:n { \tl_to_str:n {#1} } }
\cs_new:Npn \__MY_if_fp_aux:n #1
  { \__MY_if_fp_state_space:w #1~ \s_stop }
\cs_new:Npn \__MY_if_fp_state_space:w #1 ~ #2 \s_stop
  {
    \tl_if_empty:nF {#2} f
    \__MY_if_fp_state_sign:N #1 \s_stop
    \q_nil
  }
\cs_new:Npn \__MY_if_fp_state_sign:N #1
  {
    \use_none_delimit_by_s_stop:w #1 f \s_stop
    \my_if_digit:NTF #1
      \__MY_if_fp_state_int:N
      {
        \token_case_meaning:NnF #1
          {
            + \__MY_if_fp_state_sign:N
            - \__MY_if_fp_state_sign:N
            . \__MY_if_fp_state_frac_req:N
          }
          f
      }
  }
\cs_new:Npn \__MY_if_fp_state_frac_req:N #1
  {
    \use_none_delimit_by_s_stop:w #1 f \s_stop
    \my_if_digit:NTF #1
      \__MY_if_fp_state_frac:N
      f
  }
\cs_new:Npn \__MY_if_fp_state_int:N #1
  {
    \use_none_delimit_by_s_stop:w #1 \use_none_delimit_by_q_nil:w \s_stop
    \my_if_digit:NTF #1
      \__MY_if_fp_state_int:N
      {
        \token_case_charcode:NnF #1
          {
            . \__MY_if_fp_state_frac:N
            e \__MY_if_fp_state_exp:N
          }
          f
      }
  }
\cs_new:Npn \__MY_if_fp_state_frac:N #1
  {
    \use_none_delimit_by_s_stop:w #1 \use_none_delimit_by_q_nil:w \s_stop
    \my_if_digit:NTF #1
      \__MY_if_fp_state_frac:N
      {
        \token_if_eq_charcode:NNTF #1 e
          \__MY_if_fp_state_exp:N
          f
      }
  }
\cs_new:Npn \__MY_if_fp_state_exp:N #1
  {
    \use_none_delimit_by_s_stop:w #1 f \s_stop
    \my_if_digit:NTF #1
      \__MY_if_fp_state_expnum:N
      {
        \token_case_meaning:NnF #1
          {
            + \__MY_if_fp_state_exp:N
            - \__MY_if_fp_state_exp:N
          }
          f
      }
  }
\cs_new:Npn \__MY_if_fp_state_expnum:N #1
  {
    \use_none_delimit_by_s_stop:w #1 \use_none_delimit_by_q_nil:w \s_stop
    \my_if_digit:NTF #1
      \__MY_if_fp_state_expnum:N
      f
  }
\prg_new_conditional:Npnn \my_if_digit:N #1 { TF }
  {
    \if_int_compare:w 1 < 1#1\exp_stop_f:
      \prg_return_true:
    \else:
      \prg_return_false:
    \fi:
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff


Thanks so much! What are the t doing before and after calling \__MY_if_fp:n?

Why use sometimes \token_case_meaning and sometimes \token_case_charcode?

Follow-up question here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/727833/17200

@Vincent I use an \if:w test for performance reasons. The t is checked against the first non-expandable token found. Whenever I get the result that the parsed input is not a valid float I leave f so that \if:w sees tf which is false. If \__MY_if_fp:n absorbs the entire input without leaving f the second t following it is found and the result is true.

@Vincent The reason for \token_case_meaning:NnTF vs \token_case_charcode:NnTF is simple: \token_case_meaning:NnTF is faster (though only by a very slim margin), and since I stringify the input we can't use meaning to compare to e (which then would have different category codes and thus be false), so whenever only category 12 tokens are needed I use \token_case_meaning:NnTF in the above, and else \token_case_charcode:NnTF.
