Check if an input is a dim or a skip/muskip in an expandable way?
I am wondering how to create efficient expandable functions in LaTeX3:
\check_if_dim:n
\check_if_skip:n
\check_if_muskip:n

that would check if an argument can be parsed as a dimension, a skip or a muskip variable. I am not looking for a whole parser of dimexpr but raw dimensions that can be expressed as a floating-point number with units and optional rubber components for skip/muskip variables.
My starting code is this one by Skillmon from this post that parses efficiently a floating-point number.
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand\MYeckiffp{m m m}{
  \MY_if_fp:eTF{#1}{#2}{#3}
}
\prg_generate_conditional_variant:Nnn \MY_if_fp:n { e } { TF }
\prg_new_conditional:Npnn \MY_if_fp:n #1 { TF, T, F, p }
  {
    \if:w
        t
        \tl_trim_spaces_apply:nN {#1} \__MY_if_fp:n
        t
      \prg_return_true:
    \else:
      \prg_return_false:
    \fi:
  }
\cs_new:Npn \__MY_if_fp:n #1
  { \exp_args:No \__MY_if_fp_aux:n { \tl_to_str:n {#1} } }
\cs_new:Npn \__MY_if_fp_aux:n #1
  { \__MY_if_fp_state_space:w #1~ \s_stop }
\cs_new:Npn \__MY_if_fp_state_space:w #1 ~ #2 \s_stop
  {
    \tl_if_empty:nF {#2} f
    \__MY_if_fp_state_sign:N #1 \s_stop
    \q_nil
  }
\cs_new:Npn \__MY_if_fp_state_sign:N #1
  {
    \use_none_delimit_by_s_stop:w #1 f \s_stop
    \my_if_digit:NTF #1
      \__MY_if_fp_state_int:N
      {
        \token_case_meaning:NnF #1
          {
            + \__MY_if_fp_state_sign:N
            - \__MY_if_fp_state_sign:N
            . \__MY_if_fp_state_frac_req:N
          }
          f
      }
  }
\cs_new:Npn \__MY_if_fp_state_frac_req:N #1
  {
    \use_none_delimit_by_s_stop:w #1 f \s_stop
    \my_if_digit:NTF #1
      \__MY_if_fp_state_frac:N
      f
  }
\cs_new:Npn \__MY_if_fp_state_int:N #1
  {
    \use_none_delimit_by_s_stop:w #1 \use_none_delimit_by_q_nil:w \s_stop
    \my_if_digit:NTF #1
      \__MY_if_fp_state_int:N
      {
        \token_case_charcode:NnF #1
          {
            . \__MY_if_fp_state_frac:N
            e \__MY_if_fp_state_exp:N
          }
          f
      }
  }
\cs_new:Npn \__MY_if_fp_state_frac:N #1
  {
    \use_none_delimit_by_s_stop:w #1 \use_none_delimit_by_q_nil:w \s_stop
    \my_if_digit:NTF #1
      \__MY_if_fp_state_frac:N
      {
        \token_if_eq_charcode:NNTF #1 e
          \__MY_if_fp_state_exp:N
          f
      }
  }
\cs_new:Npn \__MY_if_fp_state_exp:N #1
  {
    \use_none_delimit_by_s_stop:w #1 f \s_stop
    \my_if_digit:NTF #1
      \__MY_if_fp_state_expnum:N
      {
        \token_case_meaning:NnF #1
          {
            + \__MY_if_fp_state_exp:N
            - \__MY_if_fp_state_exp:N
          }
          f
      }
  }
\cs_new:Npn \__MY_if_fp_state_expnum:N #1
  {
    \use_none_delimit_by_s_stop:w #1 \use_none_delimit_by_q_nil:w \s_stop
    \my_if_digit:NTF #1
      \__MY_if_fp_state_expnum:N
      f
  }
\prg_new_conditional:Npnn \my_if_digit:N #1 { TF }
  {
    \if_int_compare:w 1 < 1#1\exp_stop_f:
      \prg_return_true:
    \else:
      \prg_return_false:
    \fi:
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

Question:

How to efficiently check dim/skip/muskip in an expandable way using the same strategy as above?

Bonus question:

Why in the code provided above sometimes \token_case_meaning is used, and sometimes \token_case_charcode? What difference would it make to use \token_case_charcode everywhere instead?

EDIT : Context: I am doing this kind of things in a generic programming context. TeX not being a statically-typed language, we cannot branch over the type... because there is no type. However we can kind of infer a type from how an input can be successfully parsed, and branch over that. I am trying to achieve very generic user-level functions that can dispatch to the correct expl3 function depending on the input.

I feel I've said this before ... why are you doing this?

@JosephWright I added some context.

I feel you are doing this the wrong way (and massively inefficiently) you could look at latex font commands such as \fontsize{..}{..} or picture mode commands such as \put(..,..)  that take either a number or a length, with a number being taken as a multiplier for a default unit. In both cases this is achieved with just a couple of primitve TeX assignments, and no character by character parsing of the input.

what kind of erroneous input are you trying to catch? if you want to do something sensible if, say, the user omits the units, @DavidCarlisle's approach will work. but if you're worried about somebody using \vincent_dim_setter:n { fred \input{freaky%_file+name.tex} }, it won't. but then the question is what degree of inefficiency are you prepared to accept to avoid errors? is it OK if your function takes an hour to produce a page, provided it will catch any invalid input? it's not clear what purpose this would serve, so I assume you want to catch some more limited kind of problem, but what?

Please note that my code parses for scientific notation, that's not supported for numeric input to TeX registers, 1.5e2pt is not valid, so you'd also have to alter my code above if you want to reuse parts of that.

With Luametatex you can use the \ifchknum and \ifchkdim primitves to check whether the argument is a number or dimension.
\starttext

\doloopoverlist{10,12pt,bold}
  {\recursestring:
   \ifchkdim\recursestring\or
     The argument is a dimension.
   \orelse\ifchknum\recursestring\or
     The argument is a number.
   \else
     The argument isn't a number or dimension.
   \fi
   \par}

\stoptext


When you use these checks you have to place the dimension check before the number because otherwise 12pt would count as a valid number.
With the usage of the variants \ifchkdimension and \ifchknumber this problem can be avoided and now checking for the number before dimension works as expected.
\starttext

\doloopoverlist{10,12pt,bold}
  {\recursestring:
   \ifchknumber\recursestring\or
     The argument is a number.
   \orelse\ifchkdimension\recursestring\or
     The argument is a dimension.
   \else
     The argument isn't a number or dimension.
   \fi
   \par}

\stoptext

